# Host key verification failed even though I use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Tags: ssh, console

I try to run:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ${REGR_IP_ADDR}/deploy_jar.sh 1
```

and I get

```
14:02:54 Host key verification failed.

14:02:54 lost connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StrictHostKeyChecking` does not turn off the verification, if you already stored the public key of this host. Common combination is with `UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`, which makes sure that there is no other previous public key.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  ${REGR_IP_ADDR}/deploy_jar.sh 1
```

Should do the job for you. But note that it is not recommended in live environment, because it is the only mechanism protecting you against MITM attack.

Comment: Thanks. so I need `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` as well? or just `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` ?

Comment: Both of them as written in the answer above.

Comment: i still get `Host key verification failed.`